# Referencing locally declared variable into an array for data for chartjs

Tags: javascript, eclipse, chart.js

I'm trying to reference a value which stores a model's property from the session.

```
var value = '${foo.property}';
```

Now using chartjs I try to reference the value as one of the data for the graph

```
 myChart = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');

         massPopChart = new Chart(myChart, {
             type: 'bar' ,
             data: {
                 labels:['Sample Column' , '2nd Low Value Column'],
                 datasets:[{
                     label: 'Sample Value Column',
                     data:[

               //------REFERENCE OVER HERE
                         value, 
                         3000
                     ],
                     backgroundColor:[
                         'rgba(255,99,132,0.6)',
                         'rgba(54,162,235,0.6)'
                     ]
                 }]
             }, 
             options:{}
         });
```

From inspecting elements the value I get is not the value of the model property but the word value itself

I've read up on javascript tutorials none of their lessons about variables help me with this issue

I learned that referencing variables in javascript is different so can someone enlighten me on this

EDIT: I've also tried directly referencing '${foo.property}' in the data segment and I get the value but it returns as a String, I have tried using parseInt and Number to try to convert but to no avail

Comment: Try **var value = foo.property**

Comment: Javascript and Java are completely different programming languages - please only use the correct tag.

Comment: it was related in a way(session variable was set using java servlets) but i'll take note of that when posting next time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to a comment from a certain user(who deleted it for some reason), I found that removing the quotes and directly referencing the model property in the data segment will do just what I need

```
 data:[
     ${foo.property} , //NOT '${foo.property}'
     3000
 ],
```

referencing a variable into the data segment still has that issue where the name of variable is what's used rather than the assigned value

Comment: It’s not **’$(foo.property)’** if you look closer, it’s **‘${foo.property}’**

Comment: :) Actually **‘${foo.prperty}’** is a string interpolation, and only useful if you place a variable inside a string. If there’s no string before and after it you don’t need it, **foo.property** is enough.